# gstreamer streaming to nginx rtmp server

Tags: nginx, gstreamer, rtmp, beagleboneblack

PS: First time gstreamer user here. :)

Im trying to stream video from a logitech c920 webcam connected to a beaglebone using gstreamer to an nginx server. But somehow rtmpsink is failing on me. However, with filesink im able to save the video on the beaglebone. Though I still have some frame loss issues and no audio, I want the streaming part to be working first. The command Im using is

```
GST_DEBUG=4 GST_DEBUG_FILE=gst2.log gst-launch-1.0 -v -e uvch264src device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true average-bitrate=5000000 iframe-period=33  src.vidsrc  ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://192.168.1.104:1935/hls/movie"
```

My debug output is here. 
[gist](https://gist.github.com/r3dsm0k3/c584d63e4855832cb775)

gstreamer just quits within 5 seconds.

I verified that the streaming server works. But from the client, gstreamer is not giving me any kind of error messages. Or I dont know how to debug it properly.

Im stuck on this issue for the last so many days. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

### Update 1

:
 Im able to send a local file to my rtmp server with ffmpeg and server is handling it as expected.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /Users/r3dsm0k3/10.mp4 -vprofile baseline -ar 44100 -ac 1 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.4:1935/hls/example
```

Tried gstreamer with fakesink and it doesn't give any errors.

### Update 2

Tried with v4l2src as well, without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It was rather simple but on the server side of things.

I had to add  `publish_time_fix off;` in the nginx config for rtmp server.

Thanks to this [blog](http://www.sk89q.com/2014/05/broadcasting-a-video-playlist-to-nginx-rtmp-module/).

Comment: I was using this config option for a long time but with gstreamer 1.14 it stopped working. Gstreamer was failing with **WriteN, RTMP send error 32** and **WriteN, RTMP send error 9**.

I removed `publish_time_fix off;` it and I can publish again. 

They changed flvmux to use GstAggregator I guess it needs the default `publish_time_fix`.